# GetAll groupjoin that populates list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a GetAll statement that grabs every person and populates the collection of tickets they have. My classes are abbreviated as follows:

```
    public class Person
    {
      public int Id {get;set;}
      public string Name {get;set;}
      public ICollection<Ticket> Tickets {get;set;}
    }

    public class Ticket
    {
      public int Id {get;set;}
      public int PersonId {get;set;}
      public string MovieName {get;set;}
    }
```

I'm using entity framework to generate the classes with linq from the dbcontext to populate the request.

```
    public async Task<List<Person>> GetPersonsAsync()
    {
        return await _context.Person.GroupJoin(_context.Ticket,
                p => p.Id,
                c => c.PersonId,
                (per, tix) => PopulatePerson(per,tix) )
            .ToListAsync();
    }

    private Person PopulatePerson(Person per, IEnumerable<Ticket> tix)
    {
        per.Tickets= tix.ToList();
        return per;
    }
```

This works but I had to create the seperate private PopulatePerson method in order to accomplish this. How can I avoid creating a private method and populate the list of tickets in the same GroupJoin statement?

Comment: If you are using EF, why are you using `GroupJoin`? Shouldn't your `Person` class already get the `Tickets` if you use `Include(p => p.Tickets)` on your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Include()` and let EntityFramework do the Joins for you:

```
public async Task<List<Person>> GetPersonsAsync()
{
    return await _context.Person
        .Include(p => p.Tickets)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I forgot the keyword Include and was accidentally recreating all the work. I knew there was something off haha.